# UIWebView webViewDidStartLoad Sometimes Not Firing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a UIWebView in my view controller and have set its delegate to the view controller via code (i.e. not through IB).  I have also setup the appropriate delegate methods: shouldStartLoadWithRequest, webViewDidStartLoad, webViewDidFinishLoad and didFailLoadWithError.

In my view controller's viewDidLoad method I load an appropriate URL with this code:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:reqURL];
```

95% of the time everything works great and the page loads in the UIWebView object and displays as expected.  Occasionally, however, the page doesn't load.

After stepping through my code I realized that on the times that it doesn't work the shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method fires, but webViewDidStartLoad doesn't.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?  I couldn't find anything on Stack Overflow that specifically addressed this unique issue I'm having and am slowly reaching my breaking point.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any condition at which you `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`implementation doesn't return `YES`?

Comment: Good point... I actually don't return YES in shouldStartLoadWithRequest and will update my code to do that. But even though I didn't have it returning YES it still loads the web content on the times it does work.

Comment: Why it does work even though you didn't always return `YES` is something I don't really know. But I believe it might be a good lead to explain the inconsistent behavior. Anyway, can you share your implementation of `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`?

Comment: Dude, you rock!  I have been testing tons since you suggested I return YES and things are working perfectly.  If you want to submit that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If this is the case and you forgot to put the `return YES` in than you should have been given a warning that says something like `warning: control reaches end of non-void function` did you not just look at the warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make sure that your `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` implementation returns `YES` for all conditions at which you need your webView to load.